# How to extract numbers from Two-Dimensional Array of Objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, average

I have a two-dimensional object array which becomes filled with student names and grades. Each student has its own row and the first column contains the student names and then next 4 columns contain test grades. I need to find the average of each student's tests but I don't know how to average each row's double values. I also need to find the average of all the tests in the data base. Can someone show me how to do this?

```
public class StudentGrades extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Object[][] database = new Object[14][5];
    int studentCount = 0;
```

...

```
private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                               
    //declare variables
    double grade1 = Double.parseDouble(test1.getText());
    double grade2 = Double.parseDouble(test2.getText());
    double grade3 = Double.parseDouble(test3.getText());
    double grade4 = Double.parseDouble(test4.getText());
    String name = firstInput.getText() + " " + lastInput.getText() + ":";

    if (grade1 >= 0 & grade1 <= 100 & grade2 >= 0 & grade2 <= 100 & grade3   >= 0 & grade3 <= 100 & grade4 >= 0 & grade4 <= 100){

        //add data
        database[studentCount][0] = name;
        database[studentCount][1] = grade1; 
        database[studentCount][2] = grade2;
        database[studentCount][3] = grade3;
        database[studentCount][4] = grade4;

        //add to student count
        studentCount = studentCount + 1;

        //limit number of students
        if (studentCount == 15){
            addButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }  
    else {
        errorLabel.setText("Please Enter Valid Data.");
    }
```

Comment: Are you required to use an array of arrays? Or is that just how you chose to solve this problem? If you can choose the design you may want to consider creating a Student class that encapsulates a name and a List of grades.

Comment: Don't use this data structure. Use something like a map with String keys and `List<Integer>` values. Also, you might be interested in the reduction functions included in the Java 8 Stream API.

Comment: 1. You should not be using `Object[][] database` for this. 2. How have you tried to calculate the average?

Comment: Use objects for this. Double arrays of values are NOT a good way to store data which should be represented as a Student object with a list of grades. Doing it this way makes it harder to read.

Comment: It is required that I use a two-dimensional array for this program.

Answer (score 1):

An example of a reasonable *Student* class design could be something like this (implementation left blank):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Student {
    private String name;
    private List<Double> grades;

    public Student(String name) {
        // TODO 
    }

    public void addGrade(double grade) {
        // TODO
    }

    public double average() {
        // TODO 
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
            "Student: %s\nAverage Grade: %f\n", 
            this.name, 
            this.average()
        );
    }
}

class TestStudent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student s = new Student("Hunter");
        s.addGrade(100);
        s.addGrade(90);
        s.addGrade(0);
        s.addGrade(85);
        s.addGrade(75);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the code as you currently have:

```
Object[][] database = new Object[14][5];
```

We can add a few things to make it more friendly to the reader

```
final int STUDENTS = 14;
final int GRADES = 4;
Object[][] database = new Object[STUDENTS][GRADES + 1];
```

In order to be able to check the average values

```
public double getStudentAverageGrade(Object[] student)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < GRADES; i++) // forEach grade
    {
        gradesSummatory += (double) student[i + 1]; // plus one is added since we ignore first value (which is students name)
    }
    return gradesSummatory/GRADES;
}
```

Now, to be able to see the average of ALL the students, its just easier since we simply have to implement the method previously created.

```
public double getAverageGrade()
{
    double avgSummatory = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < STUDENTS; i++)
    {
        avgSummatory += getStudentAverageGrade(database[i]);
    }
    return avgSummatory/STUDENTS;
}
```

By saying this I don't consider it being a really optimal solution (you could sum all the elements and divide only once) but it's the most expressive non-object oriented solution imo. I'd rather abstract these elements/objects into different classes such as Student so as to reuse code as much as possible. But for this case, this could do the trick.